# Current timestamp in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp

Please help me with the following:

```
CREATE TABLE "tblSample"
(
    id_smpl         int not null primary key,
    timestamp_smpl  current_timestamp,
)
go
```

I am trying to create a table with current timestamp in it and I get an error of incorrect syntax.

Any tips?

Comment: you haven't actually specified a field type, e.g. `timestamp_smp datetime2 default current_timestamp`. In other words, learn basic SQL syntax...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE tblSample(
id_smpl            int not null primary key,
timestamp_smpl     datetime not null DEFAULT current_timestamp
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`CREATE TABLE table_name (
         id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
         cur_timestamp TIMESTAMP(8)
       );`

Have to give value in the timestamp.